# Checking external link slow on EC2 instance

Tags: php, curl, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to write a script that check if an external CSS link exists.

On my local machine I've tried

```
<?php
$link = 'http://fakewebsite.com/css/foobar.css'
$translate_feed = @file_get_contents($link);
if($translate_feed === false) {
echo 'failed';
}else{
echo 'works';
}
```

I've also tried similar solutions found on stackoverflow

```
$file_headers = @get_headers( 'http://example.com/image.jpg' );

$is_the_file_accessable = true;

if( strpos( $file_headers[0], ' 200 OK' ) !== false ){
    $is_the_file_accessable = false;
}

if( $is_the_file_accessable ){
    // THE IMAGE CAN BE ACCESSED.
}
else
{
    // THE IMAGE CANNOT BE ACCESSED.
}
```

And used CURL

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
if($retcode==200) echo 'YES';
else              echo 'NO';
```

Each of these solutions work fine on my local dev box but when I try and run them on my ec2 instance it takes forever to run then I get a 503 from Varnish. I'm not sure what's making it hang, any ideas? thanks

Comment: [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) is curl installed on your ec2 instance?

Comment: You're missing a closing quote in your first code snippet: `echo 'failed;`. Guessing that's just a typo. Do you get any errors if you remove the error suppression (`@`)?

Comment: So you're saying that the 503 error reported from Varnish isn't returning a real 503 status or the whole thing is just slower than what you'd expect?

Comment: @cske yes php5.6-curl is installed. Removing the @ does change anythings, still hangs when visiting in a browser and calling on the command line, the command does fail eventually with " failed to open stream: Connection timed out ".

Comment: @apokryfos when you visit the script in the browser varnish throws a 503 after a long time of waiting, on the command line if too is extremely slow but does output a response but only after ~3 minutes.